# How do i add a Listview in a Treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, treeview

Is there a possibility to add a Listview in a Treeview?

What i want should look like this:

[image]

I created a class for this:

[image]

with only name and children everything works fine but when i want to add a list nothing really happens.

The list and the treeView seperate are working fine but i need to combine them and add a List to the leafs of the Tree.

My xaml code:

[image]

If anyone have a better idea how to display this i would also be really greatful.

I hope you can help me.

BR Max

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code (something to read: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245), [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)). Add the code as code-formatted text to your question. Also, the blue wiggly lines indicate some error. Visual Studio will tell you in detail what this error is. Don't just show us blue wiggly lines and let us blind-guess the problem. Tell us about the error Visual Studio is telling you about...

Comment: With regard to your question posed in the title "_How do i add a Listview in a Treeview?_" You would do it in the same manner as you would do with any other UI element. With regard to putting a UI element in a (Hierarchical)DataTemplate; there really is no difference in whether you would put a ListView, a button, a text label, an image, or some other UI element into a DataTemplate. What i am basically trying to say with my comment here: I do not really understand the reasoning/motivation behind your question. Your question as currently written is unclear to me.

Comment: Is `SubList` a public property? Please post your code. An `HierarchicalDataTemplate` cannot have two root elements. You should use a `Panel`.